# Defining a method for an instance of a class

Tags: ruby

How do you define a method on an instance of a class and this method is only for the instance and not others?

Please can someone provide a use case for this feature?

Comment: The most common use case is a (so-called) class method. In Ruby, a class is an object. If you want to add a method to a single class (as opposed to all classes), you need a way to define that method on a per-object level (the object being the class). Something like `def Date.today ; ... ; end` is the same as `def obj.foo ; ... ; end`.

Comment: For another perspective: it allows a [prototype-based](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming) approach where the objects are the primary entities and no (named) classes are needed. You can just start with a blank `Object` instance and add methods to it to make it respond to corresponding messages. Once your object is set up, you can create new objects based on that object (or prototype) by `clone`-ing it.

Comment: Not an answer but I want to say that it is refreshing to see someone learning ruby core first and trying to understand it rather than just jumping into rails. In my opinion too many people start with rails and then try and "figure out" ruby from there, which can be a very trying process.

Comment: If you want to understand Ruby and the class/instance differentiation, you may end up needing to learn some more about the [Eigenclass](https://medium.com/rubycademy/understanding-the-eigenclass-in-less-than-5-minutes-dcb8ca223eb4) underpinnings.

Answer (score 3):

Defining a singleton method on an object gives you an object with some new properties. That's it, not more, not less.

Sure, you could achieve the same in another way - create a new class with the desired properties and instantiate it, mix in a module that adds the necessary behavior. And in most practical cases you'd probably do just that.

But think about tests for example where you need to mock some object's method (sure, RSpec framework provides a better way to do this, but still). Or you're debugging the code in REPL and would like to mock some method (for example, to avoid unnecessary side effects). In such cases defining a singleton method is the easiest (fastest) way to get things done.

Just don't think about this "feature" as a separate feature. Because it's not. It is just a consequence of how the Ruby object model works - focus on the latter. I strongly recommend [this book](https://pragprog.com/titles/ppmetr2/metaprogramming-ruby-2/) for that...

Answer (score 1):

Class methods are called on the class itself which is why in the method declaration, it will always state def `self.class_method_name.`

Whereas instance methods are called on a particular instance of the class (Not class itself) and they are declared like regular methods i.e `def instance_method_name.`

For example:

```
class Car
  def self.class_method
    puts "It's a class method"
  end

  def instance_method
    puts "It's an instance method"
  end
end


Car.class_method => "It's a class method"
Cat.instance_method => undefined method 'instance_method' for Car:Class

Car.new.instance_method => "It's an instance method"
Car.new.class_method => undefined method 'class_method' for Car:Class
```

For the usecase, here is an example from the Rails:

```
class Car < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :owner
  has_many :passengers

  def self.get_cars(owner) # This is a class method
    Car.includes(:passengers).where(owner: owner).order(created_at: :desc)
  end
end
```

With `Car.get_cars(owner)` method, you can get all the cars with your own logic.